# Process extjs store proxy data after data recieved

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using extjs sencha store for storing data. I make a proxy call to a web-service to get data. I refresh the data using store.load() function.

I am looking to edit the data that is received before it is given to the grid.

I know about the load event, but this function is executed after the load is completed and data is populated with the current data.

```
listeners : {
        'load' : function(store,records, options) {
    } 
},
```

I am looking to see how I can edit the returned data from web-service before it is assigned to the store. Basically data returned from my webservice is in different format than the format we give to extjs datagrid. So, want to do a data operation before we give to the grid. Hope we can do this.

Thx

Comment: You can overwrite the Ext.data.Proxy which has the relevant create, read, update, delete methods so overwrite the read, and you will get the information before you get the results put into your store.

Comment: I tried this function but now I see the data that is shown to the grid is empty

Comment: read: function(operation, callback, scope) {
            var thisProxy = this;
            var cityInfo = [
                    {name: 'New Jersey',    location: 'East Coast'},
                    {name: 'California',    location: 'West Coast'}    ];
            
           operation.resultSet = new Ext.data.ResultSet({
                records: cityInfo,
                total  : cityInfo.length
            });
 
            if (typeof callback == "function") {
                callback.call(scope || thisProxy, operation);
            }
    }

Comment: Anything wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 3):

Model mappings can help you do this. There is a conversion function that can be supplied as well. Here is the example from the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field):

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                var fullName  = record.get('name'),
                    splits    = fullName.split(" "),
                    firstName = splits[0];

                return firstName;
            }
        },
        'name', 'email',
        {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'gender', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Unknown'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks..Can this be used to transform one JSON completely to another ? Ideally I am looking to convert the incoming webservice data to a new json data. We can do this by this method ?

Comment: ideally you would do this on the server side.

Comment: ya..so, the webservice is a generic webservice that is also being given to external public..since we are building a layer on top of it, we do it from javascript side..

Comment: if you really want to do it that way you can reorganize the data read via Ajax.request and then use store.loadRawData to read in reorganized data.

Comment: I see..that is calling the webservice directly using the ajax request and then load the data...ya..that is what we r doing right now...i was asked to see if we can do the proxy method in store to perform the request. In that case, I would have to handle the proxy request right ? any way how we can handle the requirement via proxy ?

Comment: you would follow what @darren102 was suggesting - but i don't have any code samples to give you for that.

Comment: I am still trying to find a code sample...unable to get it so far..if you find anything, hope u can share..