# How to parse a response from extjs proxy?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs-chart

I am receiving a json object as a response from a webservice who's format is similar to:-

```
      {
         studentData:[
            {
                "history":25,
                 "science":69,
                 "maths":45
            }
           ]
      }
```

I am using the following following code to read the JSON:-

```
Ext.define('MyStore.store.dashboard.graphs.Temp', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'abc.php', 

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

         reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'studentData',

                listeners: {

                    exception: function(reader, response, error, eOpts) {
                        console.log('YT reader exception');
                        console.log(error.message, error);
                        console.log(response);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Can i parse the JSON response so that it is stored in the following format?

```
     {
         studentData:[
            {
                "subject":"History",
                 "marks":"25"    
            },
           {
                 "subject":"Maths",
                 "marks":"25"
           }
           ]
      }
```

I need to show these values in a chart having **xfield** as subject and **yfield** as marks.
Is there a listener i can append to the proxy so that i can modify the store structure according to my requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process extjs store proxy data after data recieved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633510/process-extjs-store-proxy-data-after-data-recieved). I think that thread answers all you questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of ExtJS you are using , you can change the JSON data before the store loads it.

**ExtJS 4** - You can create your own reader class by extending Ext.data.reader.Reader
class and override the getResponseData(response) and change the json and return the ResultSet.

**ExtJS 5** - You can use transform feature of Reader class and can change the response data object.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: {
                fn: function(data) {
                    // do some manipulation of the raw data object
                    return data;
                },
        scope: this
            }
        }
    },});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`transform`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform) function in your reader:

> If a transform function is set, it will be invoked just before
>   readRecords executes. It is passed the raw (deserialized) data object.
>   The transform function returns a data object, which can be a modified
>   version of the original data object, or a completely new data object.
>   The transform can be a function, or a method name on the Reader
>   instance, or an object with a 'fn' key and an optional 'scope' key.